# Why I am getting error like " Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster " on docker with magento 2.4.1

Tags: installation, elasticsearch, command-line, docker, magento2.4.1

Getting error like -   Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster

I am using docker for magento 2.4.1 while installation i am getting this error.

My docker-compose.yml.

```
    version: '3'
    services:
      nginx:
        build:
          args:
            nginx_port: 80
            nginx_version: ${NGINX_VERSION}
          context: ./docker/nginx
        depends_on:
          - php-fpm
        restart: always
        volumes:
          - ./config/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:cached
          - ./src/magento:/var/www/magento:cached
      php-fpm:
        build:
          args:
            php_version: ${PHP_VERSION}
          context: ./docker/php-fpm
        env_file:
          - .env
        depends_on:
          - cron
          - elasticsearch
          - mysql
          - rabbitmq
          - redis-fpc
          - redis-obj
          - redis-ses
        restart: always
        volumes:
          - ./src/magento:/var/www/magento:cached
          - ./config/composer/auth.json:/var/www/.composer/auth.json:cached
          - ./config/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini:cached
      cron:
        build:
          args:
            php_version: ${PHP_VERSION}
          context: ./docker/cron
        restart: always
        volumes:
          - ./src/magento:/var/www/magento:cached
      mysql:
        environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
          - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
          - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
        image: percona:${MYSQL_VERSION}
        ports:
          - "3306:3306"
        restart: always
        volumes:
          - mysql-log:/var/log/mysql
          - mysql-lib:/var/lib/mysql
      redis-obj:
        image: redis:${REDIS_VERSION}
        ports:
          - "6379:6379"
        restart: always
      redis-fpc:
        command: redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
        image: redis:${REDIS_VERSION}
        ports:
          - "6380:6380"
        restart: always
        volumes:
          - ./config/redis/fpc.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
      redis-ses:
        command: redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
        image: redis:${REDIS_VERSION}
        ports:
          - "6381:6381"
        restart: always
        volumes:
          - ./config/redis/ses.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
      elasticsearch:
        image: elasticsearch:${ELASTICSEARCH_VERSION}
        environment:
          - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
          - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx2g -Xms2g"
          - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
          - http.cors.enabled=true
          - http.cors.allow-origin=*
          - cluster.name=adlp-cluster
          - discovery.type=single-node
        ulimits:
          memlock:
            soft: -1
            hard: -1
        volumes:
          - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        ports:
          - 9200:9200
        networks:
          - elastic
        #healthcheck:
        #    test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl --silent --fail localhost:9200/_cluster/health || exit 1"]
        #    interval: 30s
        #    timeout: 30s
        #    retries: 3
        restart: always
      rabbitmq:
        image: rabbitmq:${RABBITMQ_VERSION}-management
        ports:
          - "5672:5672"
          - "15672:15672"
        restart: always
    volumes:
      mysql-log:
      mysql-lib:
      data01:
        driver: local
    networks:
      elastic:
        driver: bridge
    
    /*******************My .env file *********************************/
    
    # Versions
    NGINX_VERSION=1.18
    PHP_VERSION=7.4
    MAGENTO_VERSION=2.4
    MYSQL_VERSION=8.0
    REDIS_VERSION=6
    ELASTICSEARCH_VERSION=7.6.2
    RABBITMQ_VERSION=3.8.9
    
    # MySQL
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=magento
    MYSQL_USER=magento
    MYSQL_PASSWORD=magento
    MYSQL_DATABASE=magento
    
    # Magento (required) - see https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-install.html
    MAGENTO_ADMIN_FIRSTNAME=Magento
    MAGENTO_ADMIN_LASTNAME=Development
    MAGENTO_ADMIN_EMAIL=deepakworldphp86@gmail.com
    MAGENTO_ADMIN_USER=dev
    MAGENTO_ADMIN_PASSWORD=password1
    
    # Magento (optional)
    MAGENTO_BASE_URL=http://m2.local.docker.com/
    MAGENTO_BACKEND_FRONTNAME=admin
    MAGENTO_DB_HOST=mysql
    MAGENTO_DB_NAME=magento
    MAGENTO_DB_USER=magento
    MAGENTO_DB_PASSWORD=magento
    # MAGENTO_DB_PREFIX
    MAGENTO_LANGUAGE=en_US
    MAGENTO_CURRENCY=USD
    MAGENTO_TIMEZONE=America/New_York
    MAGENTO_USE_REWRITES=1
    MAGENTO_USE_SECURE=1
    MAGENTO_BASE_URL_SECURE=https://m2.local.docker.com/
    MAGENTO_USE_SECURE_ADMIN=1
    # MAGENTO_ADMIN_USE_SECURITY_KEY
    # MAGENTO_SESSION_SAVE
    # MAGENTO_KEY
    # MAGENTO_CLEANUP_DATABASE
    # MAGENTO_DB_INIT_STATEMENTS
    # MAGENTO_SALES_ORDER_INCREMENT_PREFIX
    
    # Magento (optional, Magento Commerce only)
    # MAGENTO_AMQP_HOST
    # MAGENTO_AMQP_PORT
    # MAGENTO_AMQP_USER
    # MAGENTO_AMQP_PASSWORD
    # MAGENTO_AMQP_VIRTUALPORT
    # MAGENTO_AMQP_SSL
    
    # Magento (optional, Redis)
    MAGENTO_REDIS_OBJ_SERVER=redis-obj
    MAGENTO_REDIS_OBJ_PORT=6379
    MAGENTO_REDIS_OBJ_DATABASE=0
    #MAGENTO_REDIS_OBJ_PASSWORD
    #MAGENTO_REDIS_FPC_SERVER=redis-fpc
    #MAGENTO_REDIS_FPC_PORT=6380
    #MAGENTO_REDIS_FPC_DATABASE=0
    #MAGENTO_REDIS_FPC_PASSWORD
    #MAGENTO_REDIS_FPC_COMPRESS_DATA=1
    MAGENTO_REDIS_SES_SERVER=redis-ses
    MAGENTO_REDIS_SES_PORT=6381
    MAGENTO_REDIS_SES_DATABASE=0
    #MAGENTO_REDIS_SES_PASSWORD
    #MAGENTO_REDIS_SES_TIMEOUT
    #MAGENTO_REDIS_SES_PERSISTENT_ID
    #MAGENTO_REDIS_SES_COMPRESSION_THRESHOLD
    #MAGENTO_REDIS_SES_COMPRESSION_LIB
    #MAGENTO_REDIS_SES_LOG_LEVEL
    #MAGENTO_REDIS_SES_MAX_CONCURRENCY
    #MAGENTO_REDIS_SES_BREAK_AFTER_FRONTEND
    #MAGENTO_REDIS_SES_BREAK_AFTER_ADMINHTML
    #MAGENTO_REDIS_SES_FIRST_LIFETIME
    #MAGENTO_REDIS_SES_BOT_LIFETIME
    #MAGENTO_REDIS_SES_DISABLE_LOCKING
    #MAGENTO_REDIS_SES_MIN_LIFETIME
    #MAGENTO_REDIS_SES_MAX_LIFETIME

# Magento (optional, Varnish)
VCL_CONFIG=/data/varnish.vcl
```

**MY installation command.**

```
sudo docker exec -it 47fc7052a3fa  php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=https://m2.docker.com --base-url-secure=https://m2.docker.com --db-host=mysql --db-name=magento --db-user=magento --db-password=magento  --backend-frontname=admin --admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=Admin --admin-email=dkmagento@gmail.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin@123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1 --elasticsearch-host=localhost:9200 --elasticsearch-port=9200
```

Here is curl test output.

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?v&pretty"
ip         heap.percent ram.percent cpu load_1m load_5m load_15m node.role master name
172.24.0.2           22          93   2    0.78    1.13     1.39 dilm      *      c6c5a3e48cfe
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, how did you fix this? I get the same error while building on the server.

Answer (score 1):

After building up your container update host url for elasticsearch. Type following command from CLI

```
bin/magento config:set catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_hostname elasticsearch
```

By default, elasticsearch host url is `localhost`

Comment: ooo man struggling on this for like more than an hour although tried changing this same value in the database manually but don't know why it didn't worked now its working

Answer (score 0):

In your .env file the elasticsearch host is `http://elasticsearch:9200` while in your install-command elasticsearch host is set to `localhost`. Change the elasticsearch host in your Magento Configuration (Backend) to `http://elasticsearch`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case
Elasticsearch wa installed via brew (Mac) on Host.

And for access from Docker used Elasticsearch host - like **host.docker.internal**
http://host.docker.internal

just try in Docker cli

*curl -X GET "http://host.docker.internal:9200/_cat/nodes?v&pretty"*

Answer (score 0):

Make sure 'catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_hostname' is set with proper hostname in core_config_data of db table.

For local magento I have set the value to 'localhost'.
Please check screenshot for more clarification - https://i.stack.imgur.com/lynIX.png