# Getting error Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster with docker

Tags: magento2, docker, elasticsearch2

I am trying to upgrade my magento 2.3.5 to 2.4.4 and seting up magento in docker

I have installed elasticsearch as well using docker via docker-compose.yml and able to access it with elasticsearch:9200 from magento instance , but when i am running php setup upgrade command then it gives me below error
Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster

can any one let me know what can be the issue.

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Answer (score 0):

After building up your container update host url for elasticsearch. Type following command from CLI

```
bin/magento config:set catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_hostname elasticsearch
```

Or, you can manually update the elasticsearch host from Store Configurations

By default, elasticsearch host url is `localhost`

I hope this will resolve your problem

Comment: I done this step already but no luck and still same issue.

Comment: Did you flush the cache after that? Well this is the same problem I had and got it resolved

Comment: Yes I did that as well

Comment: Try to add this in your /etc/hosts file

172.17.0.1 host.docker.internal

Comment: Also check your .env file for elasticsearch host

For reference: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/352034/21432

Comment: I have not added config via env.php

Comment: directly from db